# Junit test case for testing rest resource

Tags: java, rest, junit

```
public class SignLitsource {
        @GET
        @Path("token")
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
        @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
        public Response eSignLiterature(
                @SafeString@HeaderParam("CLIENT_ROID")String roidString) {
            SignatureEmailRetriver emailRetriever = new SignatureEmailRetriver();

            String emailAddress = emailRetriever.retrieveEmailAddress(Long.valueOf(poidString));
            String pin = SignaturePin.generatePin();
            SignLiterature signLiterature = new SignLiterature();
            signLiterature.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
            signLiterature.setPin(pin);
            return Response.ok(signLiterature).build();
        }

    }
```

Trying to figure out how can I write a Junit test case.Ideas needed on writing testcase for rest resource.

Comment: What framework are you using? Jersey 2, for example, has a testing framework which you can use to unit test a resource - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jersey WebTarget Client api
Sample Code:

```
WebTarget target = target("token"); // endpoint url
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = builder.get(); // builder.post();
SignLiterature returnType = response.readEntity(new GenericType<SignLiterature>);

asserNotNull(returnType);
```